# Plymouth boot is still being shown even though in /etc/default/grub I have disabled it on a dual-boot machine

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, boot-loader, plymouth

I have disabled plymouth and it was working good/great till recently.

Sharing the contents of /etc/default/grub

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=500
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi,noaer"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
 GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Just to be sure it was taking the right entries I did -

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-4-amd64
Found memtest86 image: /memtest86.bin
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Found memtest86+ multiboot image: /memtest86+_multiboot.bin
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
```

But still the plymouth splash-screen is coming on. I am much more happier seeing the boot and kernel messages etc. just in case something goes wrong somewhere.

I also had a look at man pages of both plymouth and plymouthd to see if I could get any idea of what changed but came up empty.

For what it's worth I'm running plymouth 0.9.4-1.1

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/default/grub` still shows `splash` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, that's why plymouth is still displaying the splash screen